# Related to Chatter in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

When any changes made to our profiles in chatter that is displayed on our profile saying " This person has changed his name " so is there a possibility that we could delete this message in chatter ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No u can't delete them, but u can block them to create whenever u update your profile
from feed tracking settings

```
setup > customize > chatter > Feed tracking
```

click on User object and untick all checkboxes then save.

remember: this  will not delete your existing feeds but now it will not create feeds whenever u update your profile.

take a loook at http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_Chatter
for more info.